# I can't join specific parts from three tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have been stuck on this for quite some time and the solutions I try and look up online, I can't even make sense of since I'm very new to SQL. 
I have a database of 3 tables: users, reviews, and businesses.
Sorry if my formatting is horrible, I want to make my problem as clear as possible.

First I created my tables

```
create table businesses (
id integer primary key,
name varchar(255)
);

create table users (
id integer primary key,
first_name varchar(255),
last_name varchar(255)
);

create table reviews (
id integer primary key,
stars int, comment varchar(255),
business_id int,
user_id int,
foreign key (business_id) references businesses(id),
foreign key (user_id) references users(id)
);
```

Then I added some data to each of the tables.

```
insert into businesses (name) values ("Grundy Hollow");
insert into businesses (name) values ("Lotus Yoga");
insert into users (first_name, last_name) values ("Bradford", "Pitt");
insert into users (first_name, last_name) values ("Holly", "Berry");
insert into users (first_name, last_name) values ("Steven", "Wonder");
insert into reviews (stars, comment, business_id, user_id) values (5, "nice", 1, 2);
insert into reviews (stars, comment, business_id, user_id) values (4, "p good", 1, 1);
```

So with my knowledge(lack of), to print all of them together based on the reviews, I did the following,

```
select * from reviews, users, businesses where reviews.user_id = users.id
and reviews.business_id = businesses.id;
```

Which returned,

```
1|5|nice|1|2|2|Holly|Berry|1|Grundy Hollow
2|4|p good|1|1|1|Bradford|Pitt|1|Grundy Hollow
```

Because of the repetitive behavior, I wanted to just view the user's names, the business name, the star rating, and the comment. This is where things got nowhere for me. I tried many different approaches,

```
users.first_name, users.last_name, businesses.name, reviews.stars, reviews.comment
from reviews
join users on reviews.user_id = users.id
and businesses on reviews.business_id = businesses.id;

select users.first_name, users.last_name, reviews.stars, reviews.comment, businesses.name
from reviews
join users on reviews.user_id = users.id
and reviews
join businesses on reviews.business_id = business.id;

select users.first_name, users.last_name, reviews.stars, reviews.comment, businesses.name
from reviews
join users on reviews.user_id = users.id
and businesses on reviews.business_id = business.id;
```

None of these worked and kept on throwing syntax errors... 
What can I do so that my desired data shows?

And if I wanted to, I can I view the data of all three tables for just one particular business?

Thanks for reading guys

Comment: `select ... from t1 join t2 on ... join t3 on ... where ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close.  Here is the correct syntax, using table aliases:

```
select u.first_name, u.last_name, r.stars, r.comment, b.name
from reviews r join
     users u
     on r.user_id = u.id join
     businesses b
     on r.business_id = b.id;
```

That is, you can just chain the `join` operators in the `FROM` clause.  The `and`s don't belong (as part of the `join` operator; `and` is fine for conditions).

Comment: Ahhh I see... And as for specifying a certain business to get data from other tables, would I have to modify your solution? Or would it be a completely different approach?

Answer (score 0):

First create the join like you did previously i.e. reviews r, users u, businesses b and the where clause specifying the r.business_id = b.id, etc and then select u.first_name likewise column names.

so you get:

select u.first_name, u.last_name, r.stars, r.comment, b.name

from reviews r, users u, businesses b

where r.business_id = b.id
 
     and  r.user_id = u.id;

to view for one particular business, simply add another where clause specifying the value of the business required.